# session_id PHP e mysql

Tags: php, session

Estou fazendo uma simulação de carrinho de compras com *PHP* e *Mysql*.
Preciso armazenar uma `session_id` ou qualquer identificação de sessão do usuário, para quando ele sair eu retirar os dados que ele armazenou no banco de dados.

Já criei uma coluna no banco de dados para armazenar essa `session_id`.

Alguém pode me ajudar nessa?

Estou tentando usar $_SESSION para armazenar os produtos:

```
$dadosProdutos = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_DEFAULT);
                    if ( isset($dadosProdutos) ):
                        unset( $dadosProdutos['ProdutoCesta'] );
                        $_SESSION['cesta'] = $dadosProdutos;
                    endif;
```

Se o botão submit for clicado ele pega os dados via post e armazena na sessão. Está funcionando, mas quando eu vou inserir um novo produto ele limpa a sessão.

Comment: Supondo que você armazene a session_id, de que ela vai te servir quando o usuário sair? E como é que você vai saber que ele saiu? Não seria mais fácil guardar o carrinho na session mesmo (e passar pro DB só quando o usuário fizer login ou cadastro)?

Comment: Eu pensei nisso também, Bacco! Mas eu sei pouco sobre manipulação de session. Pode me dar uma ajuda? eu uso $_SESSION? e depois que os dados estão armazenados na session como faço para deletar os produtos por ID por exemplo?

Comment: Se você guardar os produtos num array dentro da session, o array será deletado pelo próprio PHP depois que expirar a session. Dê uma treinada nos conceitos básicos de session e uma pesquisada aqui mesmo no site, sobre "session" e "PHP" na pesquisa ali em cima para ver exemplos. Vai ser mais fácil do que começar direto com o carrinho. Eu acho legal gravar o carrinho no MySQL, pois se o usuário perder a conexão, ou reiniciar o PC não perde o carrinho, mas pra isso ele tem que estar logado no seu sistema. Aí você vai apagar depois de um numero de dias que o carrinho nao for acessado. Sem session.

Comment: Um ponto de partida: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=session+php+is%3Aquestion

Comment: Vou pesquisar sim, Bacco! Me da só uma direção?! Eu crio uma session para o carrinho? E tenho que fazer um loop na pagina do carrinho para exibir cada produto?

Comment: O Session serve para armazenar um monte de informação da mesma sessão de uso (a princípio, ela vale durante o tempo que o cliente interage com o site). O carrinho vai ser uma dessas coisas. Você pode fazer algo que gere uma estrutura do tipo `$_SESSION['carrinho'] = array( array( 'idProduto' => 19, 'qtdProduto' => 2 ), array( 'idProduto' => 7, 'qtdProduto => 1 ), array( ...` . O resto (nome dos produtos, preço etc) você pega do DB na hora de exibir (ou faz um cache na memória ou na sessão). Tou só esboçando a idéia, depois você tem que elaborar melhor.

Comment: Eu consegui armazenar os dados na session. Só que estou enviando os dados de um formulário. Toda vez que eu coloco na cesta ele limpa a sessão. $dadosProdutos = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_DEFAULT);
                        if ( isset($dadosProdutos) ):
                            unset( $dadosProdutos['ProdutoCesta'] );
                            $_SESSION['cesta'] = $dadosProdutos; @Bacco

Comment: Isso por que você está sobreescrevendo a cesta, e não acrescentando. Note que no meu exemplo é uma array de produtos, com cada produto em outra array. A solução do Dunga Cardoso logo abaixo é correta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Melhor você utilizar array na SESSION, quanto ao seu script

```
 $_SESSION['cesta'][]
```

Comment: Dunga, o caminho que você propôs é uma alternativa boa, mas seria legal você explicar como funciona sua resposta, assim tem maior chance dela ser bem pontuada.

Comment: Pessoal, eu consegui armazenar os IDs dos produtos na session e pegar os produtos dos IDs selecionados do banco de dados. Mas como eu tenho tenho até três preços no mesmo produto, ficou meio enrolado de fazer isso com session. Achei mais simples colocar os pedidos em outra tabela no banco com uma coluna pra sessão e funcionou. Vou excluir os dados do banco, após um dia ou mais. Agradeço o interesse de vocês em ajudar! Muito obrigado!

Comment: Dunga, dá para explicar melhor a resposta? assim outros podem compreender melhor o problema e a solução